# Devise added to user, when user is not logged in web page is directly going to login page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails application when I run localhost:3000, if I am not logged in, it directly goes to login page. according to the requirement, I should get a welcome statement which is mentioned on the home page.

my home page

```
    <h1>Cricket Admin Page </h1>

<% if user_signed_in?   %>
    <h2><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user)  %></h2>
    <h2><%= link_to "Add role" , new_role_path %></h2>
    <h2> <%= link_to "Modify Users", users_path%></h2>  
<% else %> 
    <h1><% Welcome to cricket App %></h1>
    <h2><% to move further please login %></h2>
<% end %>
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


 devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  resources :users 

  root 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: Can you add your `home_controller.rb` and `application_controller.rb` ?

Comment: I think you used `before_action :authenticate_user!`  in your `home` or `application` controller.

Comment: there is nothing except  index action

Comment: Have you used `before_action :authenticate_user!` anywhere in your code probably in `application_controller` ? Please check

Comment: ohh yes thank you i have used before_action :authenticate_user! it in application controller

Comment: I have added this as an answer please upvote/accept if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `before_action :authenticate_user!` from your `application_controller`

Add like this in `home_controller`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
```

or

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: ["list all actions except index"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to your application controller if you want to manage authentication in every controller that inherits from ApplicationController.

Then, in your individual controllers, where you don't need a user to be authenticated, you can use `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` and use `only:` or `except:` to skip authentication on those actions.

For instance, to skip user authentication on your home_controller index action, you can use `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[index]` in your `home_controller.rb` file.